# Does Paypal API has got any updates regarding NOSHIPPING issues? I am unable to unset shipping info prompts at paypals

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I just wanted to know if it is possible using paypal REST api that we can disable the shipping information form on paypal site. I am currently working on a site to implement cart checkouts, For fist time, I found paypal saying "We dont allow US merchants to make shippings to countries outside US". So I started saving our shipping data to my own database and left paypal to process shipping amount (which is calculated on my end) only. now, issue is that I want paypal to not to ask for the shipping address at their's end as it would be confusing for a user. Any suggestions regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do that unless you flag all your products as digital (and hope Paypal doesn't notice). That might be a violation of their TOS, however.

Another option is to use Payments Pro and do your own checkout process, where you control what data is collected and passed along (and shipping data is definitely optional).